# Could Project Catalyst explain why the iOS release process is so poor?

Tags: catalyst

The IOHK dev team is very impressive and it is somewhat startling that the Project Catalyst iOS App (and maybe Android as well?) has a janky release process.

There is no visibility and I wonder if there are  some specific Github issue that explains the problem?  My assumption is that this is because the code is written in react-native?

Any clarification will be help.

Answer (score 2):

The Catalyst app is a work in progress and has been improving over time. What was once just IOHK is now many development teams working on scores of projects, and the team responsible for Catalyst may be prioritizing the website over the iOS app, and this is not even to mention that they have to develop an Android app simultaneously as well. It is a lot of work =^).

Comment: Sure. I understand. I have been invested in ADA for a few years and I'm an iOS developer.  But this is a process level issue.  The versions of the Catalyst app have no continuity.  The fact that there is no good process to retain the QR code and PIN is not the best trade-off.  FWIW, the other teams have really nothing to do with the iOS and Android teams.